# How can I identify which master page is applied to my site content if i am viewing using modern Ui (Modern View)

Tags: sharepoint-online

I tried this API url/_api/Web?$select=CustomMasterUrl, Master
But it give me master page which are applied to classic view I want to know which master page is applied in modern view.

Eg. If I'm viewing site contents in modern view I want to know which master page is applied in the background because I want to make some changes

---

@mike 
Thank you for your valuy answer I have one doubt, 
Is it possible to make changes in the modern UI theme ? 
If yes how ? 
Ex- I want to change the default SharePoint favicon in browser tab.

My current scenario - Classic view shows favicon which I have changed in my custom master page which is my brand logo which is working fine. but if I exit classic view it change the favicon to SharePoint default favicon.
Please help me out with some inputs sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modern UI does not use ASP.NET style master pages. They use "themes". I don't think themes are exposed via the REST API. (I'll do some checking.)